# individual rating counts for a custom SharePoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list

I have a requirement to read the individual rating counts on for each of the sharepoint list item.

Ex:

- 1 star - count 32
- 2 star - count 23

  ...
- 5 star - count 2

Currently I'm using SocialRatingManager for reading the rating count. But it gives single count for all rating types.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use GetRatings Method instead of GetRating to get all rating for a given URI.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee575644.aspx

Comment: Ashish.. You are the man! I like it.. thanks for this answer. helped me a lot!